# jqGrid add item checkbox field defaulted to checked

Tags: jqgrid

Here's a simple question.  I have a jqGrid that's working great but I want set the default value for a checkbox to checked when user adds a new item.  Here's a snippet of code:

```
{name: "Active", index: "active", width: 80, align: "center", sortable: false,
 editable: true, edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: {value: "Yes:No"}}
```

I don't see anything in the documentation:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
editoptions: {value: "Yes:No", defaultValue: "Yes"}
```

(see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions).

By the way, I personally use always the `formatter: "checkbox"` for columns like you have. Moreover

```
stype: "select", searchoptions: { value: "1:Yes;0:No" }
```

can also be helpful if you allow to search for values from the column.

**UPDATED**: Free jqGrid 4.13.6 (currently 4.13.6-pre, which one can get from GitHub) supports new `stype: "checkbox"`. One can use, for example

```
stype: "checkbox", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq"], value: "true:false" }
```

to have 3-state checkbox in the filter toolbar and 2-state checkbox in the Searching Dialog. The above `searchoptions.value` value means that the checked box corresponds the value "true" und unchecked box the value "false".

Answer (score 3):

I have used this, it worked.

```
 editoptions: {value: "true:false", defaultValue: "true"}
```