# jqgrid checkbox - Set default value on add new

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to set the default value of a checkbox when the user hits the inlineNav "Add" button.

It would seem this question would contain the answer I desire

[jqGrid add item checkbox field defaulted to checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007483/jqgrid-add-item-checkbox-field-defaulted-to-checked)

but alas, it doesn't work. I am using the following entry in my colModel:

```
{name:'enabled', index:'`enabled`', width:120,editable:true, edittype:"checkbox", editoptions:{value:"1:0", defaultValue:"1"}, formatter:"checkbox", align:"center"}
```

I have tried `{defaultValue:1}, {value:"Yes:No", defaultValue"Yes"}, {defaultValue:function(){return:"1"}}` etc. but all don't seem to do the trick.

Can someone please help me? Am I missing something obvious, before I go rooting around in the source to help figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that you use not the last version of jqGrid. The problem with the usage of `defaultValue` property of `editoptions` exist in the version 4.3.0, but it's fixed in the version 4.3.1.

I make minimal modifications in the demo from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8511348/315935) on your old question. Compare [the demo which uses jqGrid 4.3.1](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/inlineNav-cloneToTop2.htm) with [the same demo which uses old version (4.3.0)](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/inlineNav-cloneToTop2old.htm) of jqGrid. If you click on "Add" button on the new demo the checkbox will be added checked which corresponds the setting

```
editoptions: {value: 'Yes:No', defaultValue: 'Yes'}
```

On the other side the demo which uses jqGrid 4.3.0 ignore the setting and create always unchecked checkbox.