# jqGrid: Form isn't showing checkbox values

Tags: jqgrid

I have the following call to load a grid:

```js
$("#searchlist").jqGrid({
    url:'./searchlibrary',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    postData: {
        type: function(){return $('select[name="searchtype"]').val();},
        criteria: function(){return getSearchData();}
    },
    colNames:['Resource Name','Unit', 'Topic','Document Type','Content Type','Select'],
    colModel :[ 
        {name:'resourceName', index:'resourceName', width:380, align:'left'}, 
        {name:'unit', index:'unitID', width:40, align:'center',sortable:true,
            sorttype:'text'}, 
        {name:'topic', index:'topicID', width:220, align:'center',sortable:true}, 
        {name:'docType', index:'docTypeID', width:97, align:'center',
            sortable:true}, 
        {name:'contentType', index:'contentTypeID', width:97, align:'center',
            sortable:true},
        {name: 'select', width:55, align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true,
            edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value:"Yes:No" },
            formatter:"checkbox",formatoptions: {disabled : false}}
    ],
    rowNum:20,
    sortname: 'resourceName',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    width:878,
    height:251
});
```

Notice the last item in the `colModel` section. Notice the editoptions section. When the grid is loaded it seems to be ignoring this. Checking the element in chrome shows the following code being generated:

```html
<input type="checkbox" value=" " offval="no">
```

Am I doing something wrong in the declaration?

## UPDATE

Here's the JSON returned:

```
 {"total":1,"page":"1","records":"4","rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["Test Resource 1","1","Topic 1","pdf","course","1"]},{"id":"2","cell":["Test Resource 2","1","Topic 1","pdf","course","2"]},{"id":"3","cell":["Test Resource 3","1","Topic 2","mp4","course","3"]},{"id":"4","cell":["Test Resource 4","1","Topic 2","wmv","course","4"]}]}
```

This still gives me 4 results all checked by default. This is what's in my colModel for select now:

```
 {name: 'select', index:'resourceID', width:55, align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value:"Yes:No", defaultValue:"No" }, formatter:"checkbox",formatoptions: {disabled : false}}
```

The first generated html for one of the select cells is this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" offval="no">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you loads the data in the grid the values for the `select` column will be filled as the checkbox with respect of the `formatter:"checkbox"`. If the value is `""` the default value can be used. So one can use `defaultValue` of the `formatoptions` to specify the default value. The HTML fragment

```html
<input type="checkbox" value=" " offval="no">
```

with `" "` value shows that you have probably wrong data with the space instead of empty string. If you need to fill the data correctly you need return from the server the data having `true`, `false`, `1`, `0`, `yes`, `no`, `on` or `off` (the case of all values are not important). See [the source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.0/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L266-276) for more details.

So you should one more time verify your data returned from the server. I personally prefer to use `1` and `0` as the input values for checkboxes.

Comment: What if you don't want this cell related to any data from the databaase? I just want to use this checkbox as a method for showing selected items in the grid.

Comment: Or, if I do assign it to a database value, how do I make it be unchecked by default?

Comment: @LoneWolfPR: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Which data you returns from the server? If you want to use predefined `formatter:"checkbox"` you should have input data which can be interpreted by the `formatter:"checkbox"`. You can use `beforeProcessing` to "normalize" the data.

Comment: @LoneWolfPR: you can use `defaultValue`. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3009397/315935) as an example, but with `formatoptions`: `formatoptions: {disabled: false, defaultValue: "No"}`

Comment: @LoneWolfPR: Could you include the JSON data returned from the server? Which values are used for `'select'` column?

Comment: I updated the original question with the JSON returned and my current colModel section for `'select'`

Comment: @LoneWolfPR: Everything looks good now. What problem you has now? The only difference that now the value after editing will `"Yes"` or `"No"` instead of `"1"` or `"0"` before. You don't wrote which version of jqGrid and jQuery you use. I hope that you use jqGrid 4.4.0 and jQuery 1.7.2. Isn't so?

Comment: I'm using Jquery 1.7.2 and JQGrid 4.4.0. The issue is that all rows show up checked by default, and I want them unchecked.

Comment: @LoneWolfPR: What you mean "checked by default"? Did you have no value for the column in the JSON used to fill the grid? Is the problem exist only in the "Add" form?

Comment: I mean. When I load data into the grid via `trigger('reloadGrid')` the rows that show up each have a check box in the last cell that is checked when it loads. I want these checkboxes to be unchecked when the data first loads.

Comment: @LoneWolfPR: In the JSON which you posted the input data for the checkbox column are "1", "2", "3", "4" instead of "0" or "1". All the data are not "0" so the checkboxs as checked.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense to me now. I thought I could have a value in that field to track and just have it checked or not. I didn't realize the value is tied specifically to whether it is checked or not. Thanks for you help again.

Comment: @LoneWolfPR: Now it's clear what you problem was. The reference on [the source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.0/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L266-276) of formatter which I posted in my answer shows that jqGrid uses `cval.search(/(false|0|no|off)/i)<0 ? " checked='checked' " : ""`. So it test (case insensitive) where *the value* for the chechbox contains `false`, `0`, `no` or `off`. If the text will be not found then the attribute `checked='checked'` will be added to the `<input>` and the checkbox will be displayed checked.

Comment: @LoneWolfPR: As I wrote before I personally use `0` or `1` in the JSON input and use `editoptions: { value:"1:0" }` in the column definition.